# React-Native - Using a Javascript Module that relies on node.js core module

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to utilize a vcard parsing module written in Javascrip but it relies on node.js core modules, fs and path.  My application is written in React-Native.  Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I can emulate the file-system and path modules of npm for use inside the vcard parsing javascript module?

The file in question is the index file of vcards-js and is located inside my node_modules folder of my application.  So app/node_modules/vcards-js/index.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
```

Comment: Look at browserify.

Comment: React Native is not running on Node, it's running on a pure Javascript environment, not only node API won't work, many Web API does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I forked vCards JS for use with React Native: https://github.com/idxbroker/vCards-js/tree/react-native

Instead of trying to emulate fs one to one, I use a package: react-native-fs
Which has very similar methods and functionality as the Node equivalent.
vCards JS only required minimal adjustments.

Feel free to use this version.

```
npm install react-native-vcards@https://github.com/idxbroker/vCards-js.git#react-native --save
```

Comment: It's funny you mention this because it's something I've actually already tried but couldn't quite get it to work @Daniel IDXBroker.  FYI there is no directory at reart-native-vcards.  If you have a working version, I would love to use yours

Comment: Sorry, we changed the repo name right after I posted this. I updated the original post to reflect the new repo location.